# Plot percentages in R as blocks

Tags: r

I have the table to the left

```
table <- cbind(c("x1","x2", "x3"), c("0.4173","0.9211","0.0109"))
```

and is trying to make the plot two the right.

[image]

Is there any packages in R, which can do, what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I would create a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix` as `matrix` can have only a single type. I assume the second column is `numeric`

Comment: Also, in `base R`, you can use a named vector and plot bars i.e. `barplot(setNames(c(0.4173, 0.9211, 0.0109), paste0("x", 1:3)))`

Comment: That's a good start.

Comment: Does the barplot helps you

Comment: What is  the easiest way to add and empty (non-filled) block on each of the blocks, so they spand to 1? And also turn it 90 degrees if possible?

Comment: You can subtract 1 from the vector, and plot along with it

Comment: Indeed it does, it's really close to what I'm trying to achieve, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R`, option would be to use `barplot` applied on a `named` vector

```
barplot(v1)
```

Or convert to two column `data.frame` with `stack` and use the `formula` method

```
barplot(values ~ ind, stack(v1))
```

---

Or we can can use `tidyverse` with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
enframe(v1, name = "id", value = 'block') %>% 
    mutate(non_block = 1 - block) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = name)) + 
        geom_col() + 
        coord_flip() + 
        theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
v1 <- setNames(c(0.4173, 0.9211, 0.0109), paste0("x", 1:3))
```